# iOS Status Bar pushing InAppBrowser down

Tags: ios, cordova, statusbar, inappbrowser

[image]This is the environment:

```
- iOS 11
- Cordova 8.0.0
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
```

The status bar pushes the InAppBrowser down and hides 20px of the displayed webpage. This was working fine in iOS 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of research I found the answer on this page:

[CB-14024 Take into account statusbar height when toolbar is enabled](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/265)

Basically this is the fix:
Look for rePositionViews in CDVInAppBrowser.m and replace accordingly.

```
- (void) rePositionViews {
   if ((_browserOptions.toolbar) && ([_browserOptions.toolbarposition isEqualToString:kInAppBrowserToolbarBarPositionTop])) {
      [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, TOOLBAR_HEIGHT + [self getStatusBarOffset], self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height - [self getStatusBarOffset])];
      [self.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(self.toolbar.frame.origin.x, [self getStatusBarOffset], self.toolbar.frame.size.width, self.toolbar.frame.size.height)];
   }
}
```